# Was Dama Fortuna from Fiona’s Prologue the witch that Fiona mentioned in Shrek 1?

Tags: shrek

In Shrek 1, Fiona said, “When I was a little girl, a witch cast a spell on me.”

Some people think she was on about the “witch” aka fortune teller, Dama Fortuna from the deleted scene “Fiona’s Prologue.”

Is that true or not?

Comment: @closevoters how is this unclear?

Comment: Because there is no person named “Dama Fortuna” anywhere in the published Shrek canon so the question is meaningless?

Comment: I thought Dama Fortuna was the Fairy Godmother? Now she's also a fortune-teller?

Comment: "Some people think" ...like who?

Comment: @F1Krazy a fortune-teller was named that in some deleted scene thing that’s completely non-canon.

Comment: @F1Krazy People on IMDB and Tv Tropes.

Comment: Historically, deleted scenes have not _automatically_ been considered non-canon; certainly the creators "wrote" (animated, whatever) them for a reason. Particularly if the deleted scene doesn't conflict with anything published, it's a valid source of information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This is a deleted alternate opening from "Shrek" in which you can see a plot outline that differs radically from the final one used.
>
> In this alternate opening, Fiona, who at this point in story development was born a full ogress to her parents [...]

Source: Description to the YouTube video [Shrek Deleted Scene-Fiona's Prolouge](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pLwINMsqvjA)

If you watch that video, you'll learn that *Dama Fortuna* provides a magic potion to Fiona which doesn't seem to work, but OTOH doesn't make matters worse (at first glance).

So the answer is no. In that different storyline *Dama Fortuna* didn't cast the spell, but more probably provided a help to lift it. In the final cinematic version she doesn't appear at all, so she can't be the witch in question.

Comment: “Dama Fortuna didn’t cast the spell, but more probably provided a help to lift it? What’s Fiona’s curse in your eyes? Being born an ogre or the spell the potion gave her?